# How to change the theme of CPTXYGraph

Tags: core-plot

I'm trying to change the theme of my graph .

My code is :

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

I thought by doing this that the border of the graph would disappear. But it didn't .

Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several parts of the graph can have border lines. Try these as well:

```
graph.borderLineStyle = nil;
graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me . I found the reason why the code 'graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.borderLineStyle = nil;' did not take effect . It must be called after the graph applying a theme while I put it before that . Anyway , thank you .